# Sending email from oracle apex UTL_SMTP with smtp server credentials

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex-5.1

Is there a way to send email using UTL_SMTP method by providing smtp server credentials which is not localhost.

i.e. SMTP service is running somewhere else but is not https secures, i want to use utl_smtp package but i dont see any function parameter that take smtp server id or password in it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use UTL_SMTP, you provide the SMTP host when you call `utl_smtp.open_connection`.

Example code (taken from Oracle docs);

```
DECLARE
  c UTL_SMTP.CONNECTION;

  PROCEDURE send_header(name IN VARCHAR2, header IN VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(c, name || ': ' || header || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
  END;

BEGIN
  c := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION('smtp-server.acme.com');
  UTL_SMTP.HELO(c, 'foo.com');
  UTL_SMTP.MAIL(c, 'sender@foo.com');
  UTL_SMTP.RCPT(c, 'recipient@foo.com');
  UTL_SMTP.OPEN_DATA(c);
  send_header('From',    '"Sender" <sender@foo.com>');
  send_header('To',      '"Recipient" <recipient@foo.com>');
  send_header('Subject', 'Hello');
  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(c, UTL_TCP.CRLF || 'Hello, world!');
  UTL_SMTP.CLOSE_DATA(c);
  UTL_SMTP.QUIT(c);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN utl_smtp.transient_error OR utl_smtp.permanent_error THEN
    BEGIN
      UTL_SMTP.QUIT(c);
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN UTL_SMTP.TRANSIENT_ERROR OR UTL_SMTP.PERMANENT_ERROR THEN
        NULL; -- When the SMTP server is down or unavailable, we don't have
              -- a connection to the server. The QUIT call raises an
              -- exception that we can ignore.
    END;
    raise_application_error(-20000,
      'Failed to send mail due to the following error: ' || sqlerrm);
END;
```

If your smtp server accepts PLAIN, LOGIN or CRAM-MD5 authentication, you need to call `utl_smtp.auth` as well, e.g.:

```
DECLARE
  c utl_smtp.connection;
BEGIN
  c := utl_smtp.open_connection(
      host => 'smtp.example.com',
      port => 25,
      wallet_path => 'file:/oracle/wallets/smtp_wallet',
      wallet_password => 'password',
      secure_connection_before_smtp => FALSE);
  UTL_SMTP.STARTTLS(c);
  UTL_SMTP.AUTH(
      c => c,
      username => 'scott',
      password => 'password'
      schemes  => utl_smtp.all_schemes);
END;
```

That said, if you're using APEX you may want to consider using APEX_MAIL instead. You configure the host in the APEX instance settings.

Documentation:

- UTL_SMTP: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_smtp.htm#ARPLS074
- APEX_MAIL: https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/APEX_MAIL.htm

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jeffrey i will checkout your provided code , one thing that i dont understand what smtp_wallet file will contains? does it contain SSL certificate keys and information and if i dont want to connect to ssl secured url can i not use wallet? and is smtp_wallet a default wallet if i want to use smtp?

Comment: The wallet is needed if you're connecting from your Oracle database to the host via SSL. If it's not a secured connection, you don't need to provide the wallet details.